# IIS web.config rewrite/redirect rule with query string

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting, web-config, query-string

I'm trying to setup a rewrite/redirect rule on a **web.config** file. I have little to no experience with IIS servers so I've been looking through solutions online, here at StackOverflow  and other forums, and already tried a number of them without success.

I must point out that I only have FTP access to the server so I can't say for sure how it has been setup (in case server setup has any influence on this).

Here are the requirements:

1. The page being redirected **can have or not ".php"**, i.e., it can either be "my-page" or "my-page.php".
2. The destination of the redirect is in a **different domain/sub-domain**
3. The page URL itself has to be quite specific (besides ".php"). For example, I have two pages, "my-page.php" and "my-page-extra.php", but I only want to redirect "my-page.php".
4. The query string present in the original can have multiple parameters in different order (or none at all)
5. I want the query string to be passed as is to the destination.

So, a typical redirect would go like this:
The visitor tries to reach:

```
https://my-domain.com/my-page.php?id=myid&param=myparam
```

or

```
https://my-domain.com/mypage?id=myid&param=myparam
```

And I want it redirected to:

```
https://my-sub-domain.my-new-domain.com/?id=myid&param=myparam
```

I have two solutions that work partially:

Solution 1: the URL works but the query string is not being passed

```
<rule name="My Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^my-page-slug(|\.php)(|\?.*)$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(.*)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://my-sub-domain.my-new-domain.com/{C:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Solution 2: the query string is passed but the URL is not as strict so it doesn't work

```
<rule name="My redirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)my-page-slug(.*)$"  ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://my-sub-domain.my-new-domain.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Install IIS on your Windows machine (IIS 10 on Windows 10 for example) and then install URL Rewrite module to play with it. You need quite a lot of trials so as to understand how to implement your own rules other than copying from others. Know how to troubleshoot too https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Answer (score 0):

You can try this rule:

```
<rule name="redirectrule1" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^my-page(|\.php)$" />
      <conditions>
         <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^my-domain.com$" />
         <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" />
      </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" url="https://my-sub-domain.my-new-domain.com/" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help. After a lot of trial and errors, this is what worked for me (I'm pretty sure there are better ways of accomplishing this using conditions but this has done the trick so far):

```
<rule name="My Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^my-page(|\.php)(|\?.*)$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://my-sub-domain.my-new-domain.com/{R:2}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```